# Match against query not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I was using like query and full text search query in my application

Like query is giving me desired results but full text query not giving correct value
Like query-

```
Select * from tablename where colname like '% value %'

select * from tablename where MATCH(colname) AGAINST(' value ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

like query is giving me correct result that is around 1000 rows but second query is giving me no result.Although both queries are similar searching for same word and in same table same column
Please highlight guys where i m wrong in second query

Answer (score 0):

A space is seen as a word terminator, so `' value '` will not match any words as there are no words with spaces in them. You should change your second query to:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tablename 
 WHERE MATCH (colname) AGAINST ('value' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

If you are searching for the exact word `'value'` it is a [stopword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) for MyISAM tables, so no rows will be returned for a MyISAM table.

From the [stopword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) page:

> To override the default stopword list for MyISAM tables, set the ft_stopword_file system variable. (See Section 5.1.4, “[Server System Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html)”).

Or you could switch to the InnoDB Engine.

Comment: still same result sir.full text query returning zero rows

Comment: So it means if we are using MYISAM table engine.full text will not work in that??is it?

Comment: @peterjoseph did you follow the links? Not with the word 'value', unless you chance the ft_stopword_file and rebuild the index.

Comment: I am sorry,but i didnt understand like how to change the ft_stopword_file and then rebuilding index

Comment: To change that variable use the [SET statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-statement.html) (as suggested by Arth's link in his answer); to rebuild the index you can simply [drop it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-index.html) and [recreate it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).